# How to strict Laravel Auth?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I need that every user would use session only once? If you loged in on one pc, I need to log out user from other. Also if IP or User-Agent changed also logout user from it.

Is there any built in options for this kind of task in laravel or I need to check each request?

Comment: Are you implement an API ?

Answer (score 3):

1. When login request generate a token which is include client_ip+random number and any other.
2. encrypt and url encode the token and send as the response.
3. each and every request check that token, if not match log out the user.